# how to dump all users hashs for active directory

Tags: active-directory

I want dump all users hashs for  active directory. Can do it?
If I can, can you give me a tools or code? 
Can I find username belong to which a IP in network?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **Windows Password Recovery Tool** to dump hashes from Active Directory. The question is why would you want to dump Active Directory hashes? (There are very few legitimate reasons to dump AD hashes.)